# Bohnanza - If no one wants the cards drawn in Step 2, does the active player HAVE to plant them in Step 3?

Tags: bohnanza

We love this game, but we have one big question about the rules for Step 2/Step 3.

For the 2 cards flipped in Step 2. If no one at all wants them, does the active player *have* to plant them come Step 3, or do they go in the discard pile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**,

They have to be planted by the active player if not traded to another player.  However,the active player can plant one (ripping out whatever was there) and then, if all his bean fields have no more than one bean planted, plant the second in the same field (ripping out the first bean).

*Don't forget that the active player can donate those beans too.*  Sometimes it is the best option.

Comment: One of the biggest sadnesses I have about Bohnanza (in the groups I play with) is that hardly ever does my group elect to "screw" a player by communally refusing to take their unwanted beans off of them.  I feel like to could be a valuable lesson for an over-ambitious player!  Maybe I'm just a big meanie though.

Comment: Don't forget that you can't rip up a field with a single bean unless all your fields have single beans.  Thus if the active player has two fields with 2+ beans in each and they can't get rid of either flipped bean, they may end up having to rip up both existing fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. However if that active player is desperate they are able to donate the cards. in a "free trade". As long as someone is willing to take them.